# When i change state everything will Re-render in React and it will cause Perfomance Problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks

So I'm coding a form which it's in a drawer and it will open with a Button click.
There is a lot of input user need to fill.

i Divided to whole form into 5 component for example 'User Info', 'Address Info', 'Bank Info', and etc.

in first i used `Context API` and the perfomance was a disaster. on every word type everything will re-render and there is obvious lag in typing. then i used `Prop drilling` and the problem didn't solve either.

[image: Plase take a look at this image]

NOTE: i tried `temporary state`, `onChange`  event and called my `original setState` after `onBlur` event and it worked. but it's not what i want. the code its so bad and dirty that way.

App component

```
 const [data, setData] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    gender: "",
    dateOfBirth: "",
    nationalCode: "",
    mobileNum: "",
    organizationalRuling: "",
    startOrder: null,
    endOrder: null,
    afterOrderEnd: [],
    cardNum1: "",
    bankName1: "",
    cardNum2: "",
    bankName2: "",
    shabaNum: null,
    country: "",
    state: "",
    city: "",
    address: "",
    zipCode: null,
    phoneNum: "",
    commissionFor: [],
    commissionPercentage: [],
    salaryFor: [],
    salaryPrice: [],
    offFor: [],
    offPercentage: [],
    username: "",
    password: "",
    userStatus: "activeUser",
  });

              <ListProfile
                data={data}
                setData={setData}
                fieldName={[
                  "firstName",
                  "lastName",
                  "gender",
                  "dateOfBirth",
                  "nationalCode",
                  "mobileNum",
                ]}/>
              <OrganizationalRuling
                data={data}
                setData={setData}
                fieldName={["organizationalRuling", "startOrder", "endOrder"]}/>
              <BankInfo
                data={data}
                setData={setData}
                fieldName={["cardNum1", "bankName1", "cardNum2", "bankName2"]}/>
              <AnotherInfoSection someProps />
              <AnotherInfoSection someProps />
```

One of my form Components

```
const ListProfile = ({ data, setData, fieldName }) => {
  return (
    <>
  const handleChange = (e, data, setData, fieldName) => {
  const { id, value } = e.target;
     setData({...data,[fieldName || id]: value.trim(),
});
};
            <TextField
              sx={{ width: "300px", margin: "10px 0" }}
              label="First Name"
              variant="outlined"
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, data, setData)}
              id="firstName"
            />
```

Why is this happening ? what is the correct way here to change parent state without re-rendering all the components ?

I Will appreciate some help

Comment: React components rerender when either state or props update, or when the parent component rerenders. In the code you've provided you don't have much state and there isn't a lot of UI to render. What performance issue are you seeing? You might try splitting the state into related "chunks" of state, i.e. state that goes with each section.

Comment: All of them have the same prop `data`, so whenever you update `data` state, all components, which are sharing that state, will be re-rendered.

Comment: As the data is being passed from parent as a props when you update the state the props gets updated hence the rerendering is happening so you need to modify the props way of sending to adjust the rerender